# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol Implementation Removal

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have a situation where Measurement Protocol implementation of Google Analytics should be removed.

I am a marketer, not a developer or a webmaster, so I have little understanding of how Measurement Protocol was implemented, even though I have these guidelines at hand: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide

The problem is that I was told that my client's webmasters do not know how Measurement Protocol Implementation should be removed as well, since they were not the ones who implemented it due to personnel changes.

Maybe you have been in a situation where Measurement Protocol was removed or you know how to do it and could help me out with guidelines?

Thanks,

Tomas

Answer (score 0):

The [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en) is a protocol used for sending hits to Google analytics.  The analytics [JavaScript snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs?hl=en) uses this protocol.

## meansurment protocol

> The Google Analytics Measurement Protocol allows developers to make HTTP requests to send raw user interaction data directly to Google Analytics servers. This allows developers to measure how users interact with their business from almost any environment. Developers can then use the Measurement Protocol to:
>
> - Measure user activity in new environments.
> - Tie online to offline behavior.
> - Send data from both the client and server.

Developers can also use the protocol directly in order to send hits to Google analytics

## analytics.js

> The analytics.js library (also known as "the Google Analytics tag") is a JavaScript library for measuring how users interact with your website. This document explains how to add the Google Analytics tag to your site.

If you want to remove google analytics tracking on your site then you should just be able to remove the JavaScript tracking snippet and this will stop tracking.

However if you have had a developer create some custom tracking app that sends data to your analytics account then unfortunately no one can help you remove that you will have to find it in your system.

Answer (score 0):

No, nobody can give you proper guidelines on that. The measurement protocol is a language agnostic, fairly high level description of how to get data into Google Analytics via http requests to a given endpoint.

Nowhere does is contain anything regarding implementation, that is totally up to the people doing the actual implementation. So they have to go through their code (mostly this is used to do server-side tracking, so I'd start on the backend code) to look for http requests to `google-analytics.com/collect`. That's as much guideline as anyone can give with the information you have provided.